# Is there a way in pycharm to close the run window and just look at the editor window using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: python, pycharm

Because of vision problems, I have to keep the font in my Python programs in pycharm larger than the default setting. When I execute any program, the run window comes up at the bottom and every time I have to start working on the Python code in the editor window, I have to close the run window using a mouse.

Is there a way to close it using the keyboard shortcut? I could not find anything in the key map but there are so many settings that there is a chance that I may have missed it.

I also tried with using the distraction free option and it works very well. However, when I tried to find something within the code, it does not bring up the in-line window that allows me to type the keyword is searched for.

Please suggest if there is any way to close the run window or if there is any workaround so that I can return to working in a larger editor window.

Thank you for any inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shift+esc` will hide the run window from within PyCharm.

If you want to access the run menu use: `ctrl+shift+A`

You can get a helpful cheatsheet of commands from within PyCharm by going to help -> Keymap Reference. This will provide the default key mapping for Windows and Linux

Comment: Thank you for a very useful response. Thank you for the added information about the cheat sheet. Marking the answer is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Preferences -> Keymap under Tool Windows -> Run.

On Mac it is CMD+4.

[image]